# Could anybody explain me what´s pass argument in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume that you have this class:

```
class ThisIsAClass

       pass
```

What´s the pass argument?, What does it do?. Im very confused about this..

Comment: It's not an argument. It's a NOP (no-operation) statement. It's there because Python's syntax requires *something* to be there even if you've got an empty class/function. (Did you not try googling at all??)

Answer (score 1):

`pass` does nothing.

It's used in cases where syntax demands a statement, but you don't want to do anything else.  In this case, you are creating a class (assuming you add the missing `:`) that has no attributes and no functionality.  If you had omitted `pass` you would get a `SyntaxError`, because colons must be followed by a valid statement on the appropriate indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply used when a statement is required, but you don't want any code actually executed.  A common place in the Except portion of a try, except block.